# Provide User with list field of images to select

Tags: 7, entities, media, javascript

I am using the flexslider module in conjunction with the views slider to create a slideshow on my Drupal project. Instead of just allowing the user to upload an image for the slideshow (the image really just acts as a background), I would like to provide the user with a list of possible images to choose from. I'm new to Drupal, so this is probably a really easy thing to accomplish, but multiple Google queries have left me in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously used [IMCE for FileField](http://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) module:

[image]

it opens a simple file browser and let you select files from configured path of server.